# creating log files using Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

Could you please tell me how can I create log files using Apache Beam. I am currently using Apex runner and I was able to produce logs only in console.

Comment: Do you mean that you have LOG.info() statements in your pipeline's code, and you're not seeing them anywhere when you run your pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I added log4j.properties in resources folder in classpath. The log messages are generated only when Commons logging API is used like
org.apache.commons.logging.Log;